# Condorcet paradox in Wikipedia

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, social-choice-theory

Can someone please explain to me the steps for the calculation of the Condorcet paradox probability $q$ in the [impartial culture model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_paradox#Impartial_culture_model)? I don't understand how does the Cauchy distribution arises from the central limit theorem.

Comment: The possible link between CLT and Cauchy distribution that i can think of is that the CLT gives us Gaussian random variables and that the ratio of two independents normal distributions is a Cauchy distribution . However i couldn't  manage to make the calculation work and get the exact same constantes in the wikipedia article.

Comment: Does someone have an idea of where could the \sqrt(2)/4 come from ?